# Gitlab integration with proprietary system for Issue notification

Tags: gitlab

What is the best way to integrate Gitlab issues and other events with a proprietary system for notifications without modifying the code.

1) Web hook does not seen to dispatch notification on issues.
2) I could read the database and implement the integration.

Any other options?

Answer (score 0):

> Web hook does not seen to dispatch notification on issues

Check again that asertion against the latest [6.4 release](http://blog.gitlab.org/gitlab-ce-6-dot-4-released/) (and this [pull request](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/5881)):

[image: http://blog.gitlab.org/images/6_4/hook.png]

> Project web hooks were extended with new types of events.
>   Web hooks can now also be triggered **when an issue is created** or a merge request is closed.

That may not cover all the issue events you want, but it is a start.